# How to search for overlapping matches for a regex pattern within a string

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl

I have this string

```
my $line = "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*"
```

and I want to find every substring starting with `M` and ending with `*` and add it to an array. This means that the above string would give me 6 elements in my array.

I have this code

```
foreach ( $line =~ m/M.*?\*/g ) {
    push @ORF, $_;
}
```

but it only gives me two elements in my array since it ignores overlapping strings.

Is there any way to get all matches? I tried googling but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use [`code within re`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression) and [`Backtracking control verbs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backtracking-control-verbs) for a little magic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*";

local our @match;

$line =~ m/(M.*\*)(?{ push @match, $1 })(*FAIL)/;

use Data::Dump;

dd @match;
```

Outputs:

```
(
  "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*",
  "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*",
  "MEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*",
  "MEAZFE*",
  "MQZEFFMAEZF*",
  "MAEZF*",
)
```

Comment: That should really be `local our @match;`, or it will fail if placed in a subroutine that's called more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to create a single regex pattern that will match all such substrings, because you're asking for *both* a greedy and a non-greedy match at the same time, and everything else in-between

I suggest you store all possible start and end positions of these substrings and use a double loop to combine all start positions with all end positions

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $line = 'MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*';

my @orf;

{
    my (@s, @e);
    push @s, $-[0] while $line =~/M/g;
    push @e, $+[0] while $line =~/\*/g;

    for my $s ( @s ) {
        for my $e ( @e ) {
            push @orf, substr $line, $s, $e-$s if $e > $s;
        }
    }
}

say for @orf;
```

#### output

```
MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*
MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*
MEAZFE*
MEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*
MQZEFFMAEZF*
MAEZF*
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be an easier way of doing this.